# (C++) INT_MAX and INT_MIN could not be resolved?

Tags: c++

I am currently taking a C++ course on [www.udemy.com](http://udemy.com) In one of the lessons the teacher is using `#include <limits>` to demonstrate the maximum number of integers an integer can have. However, when I go to include limits, everything goes well until I try to print INT_MAX and INT_MIN to see the maximum integers and the minimum integers. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "MaxInt= " << INT_MAX << endl;
    cout << "MinInt = " << INT_MIN << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Side note: I am using Eclipse Neon CDT on Windows 10 with the MinGW Compiler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want `#include <climits>` or `<limits.h>`, not `<limits>`.

Comment: Fixed it perfectly! I knew the file was there because I pressed F3 on it and it located the file, so I knew I was just typing something wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

The more modern way doesn't use those constants.

Example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits

int main () {
  std::cout << "Minimum value for int: " << std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << '\n';
  std::cout << "Maximum value for int: " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`INT_MIN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) and [`INT_MAX`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits) macros are the C way to get the maximum and minimum values of an `int`, and are defined in the "climits" header.

The "limits" header defines the class template [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), which is the C++ way of getting the range of various types.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` you to use this statement as headers `#include <climits>` or `#include <limits.h>`, instead of `#include <limits>`