# Print Minimum & Maximum Value Of Data Types in C++

Tags: c++

I was watching a tutorial on YouTube and I seen her coding this to print min and max value of data type. You can see in screenshot below. Her code was working perfectly but mine is not.

[image: Her Code Working Perfectly]

[image: My Code Giving Error]

Here's My code and It's giving error.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    // Print Minimum & Maximum Value Of Data Types
    cout << "Minimum Value Of Int Is " << INT_MAX << endl;

system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: Minimum Value Of Int is NOT INT_MAX

Comment: Sorry, INT_MAX was not working that's why I thought to check INT_MAX.

Comment: [The INT_MIN and INT_MAX macros are the C way to get the maximum and minimum values of an int, and are defined in the **climits** header.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40700872/c-int-max-and-int-min-could-not-be-resolved)

Comment: Implementation of standard libarary headers may include other headers. This is the reason the youtube tutorial code was working on that person's implementation. See [How come INT_MAX and INT_MIN resolve in C++ without <climits>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65252141/how-come-int-max-and-int-min-resolve-in-c-without-climits)

Answer (score 3):

The macro `INT_MAX` is defined in the [`<climits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits) header file. You need to include it if you want to use the macro.

If the Youtube video doesn't say anything about that, then perhaps it's not that good source for learning, and you should find another way (and it's much too easy to find bad videos than good, so I recommend you stay away from Youtube).

---

For a more C++-ish way instead include [`<limits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/limits) and use the [`std::numeric_limits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) class template.

More specifically its [`max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max) static member function:

```
std::cout << "Max int value is " << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
```

Comment: "using namespace std" should be the first code smell :D